# Separating MPEGTS Multi-queue, Padded Stream with 3 Videos

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I have output from a Python program that comes out as a single .AVI that contains 3 video streams, however, it seems that they are all combined. The videos are not concatenated, but they are interlaced. The code that produces it is pretty abstract and the only thing I can tell is that they used Gstreamer to combine the videos. I can pick out H.264 encoding and mpegts and output as an .AVI. Using ffprobe on the file I get the following output:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'output.avi':
  Duration: 00:05:00.07, start: 12045.450000, bitrate: 33695 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0xdd]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), >1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
```

I'm needing to separate the videos contained in this .AVI file, but I'm having trouble doing so using ffmpeg since there are not separate streams for each video.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this using ffmpeg or gstreamer?

Update: Upon further experimentation, it does not seem that the frames are interlaced, rather the stream of data was in some way, combined in some manner.

Update: Video output is an mpegts multiqueue, padded stream. Although it is one file, each video stream embedded in the file has its own port. I can open it in wireshark and view the data stream. I guess this changes my question to: Can you filter this single file containing multiple streams by port?

Comment: So, are you saying that you cannot go back to the original 3 video streams and must work on this `output.avi` which frames are consisting of the frames from these 3 videos in an alternating fashion like [0][1][2][0][1][2]...?

Comment: The plan is to go back and re-write code when my team gets the bandwidth to do so, but at this point in time, we just need a way to do as I described above. This code was written by a subcontractor, which had to cease working with us on this particular project due to a conflict of interest. I'm not familiar with how the frames are arranged in the output .AVI, but if they are arranged in the fashion you described, is there an easy way to separate them using ffmpeg?

Comment: Look into `select` filter, which can distribute frames to multiple outputs using a simple math on frame number: modulo 3 in your case. (The FFmpeg documentation has examples.)

Comment: Would you happen to have some sort of example command? I've been looking into the documentation and can't seem to wrap my head around how to make the command up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to separate interleaved frames:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -filter_complex select=n=3:e='mod(n\,3)+1'[v1][v2][v3] \
  -map [v1] OUTPUT1 -map [v2] OUTPUT2 -map [v3] OUTPUT3
```

If you need to specify output options, make sure to duplicate for each output file.

Comment: I have updated my question with new findings.